# What is the duality between path cover and flow?

Tags: graphs, network-flow

Let there be a bipartite directed graph $G=(V,E)$.

Let's say we have a path cover of the graph. In some texts it is said that this path cover "induces" a flow on $G$. What does this mean?

How can we extract a flow from a path cover (and similarly, extract a path cover from a flow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the flow would send $k$ units of flow along the edge $(u,v)$, where $k$ is the number of paths in the path cover that traverse that edge.

I haven't verified that this will always be guaranteed to be a valid flow for all possible path covers, but it doesn't seem like it on first glance, so more context might be needed to resolve that.

Comment: A flow is feasible if the sum of flow entering all non-source and non-sink nodes is 0. Therefore, I suppose that your flow is feasible as long as all paths start at the source and end at the sink?

Comment: @shgr1092, that sounds right to me.

Comment: Thank you very much!